# Expand spacing between tick marks on x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, axis

I want to expand the spacing between the tick marks on the x axis in R.

I have years on the x axis `c(2005:2012)` and one value per year on the y axis.
say:

```
A <- c(5,4,6,7,3,8,4,2)
B <- c(2005:2012)
plot(B, A, type="l")
```

I now need to expand the spacing between each tick mark in order to "stretch" my plot horizontally for a better overview. I am at the end of my R knowledge and I haven't found anything in the internet, please help. I only use the standard graphic packages of R.

Comment: Have you tried dragging your plot window to reshape the plot? You should also look at the `png` and `pdf` functions (or other similar functions) that will allow you to save your plot with whatever dimensions you specify.

Comment: I'll put in a plug for RStudio. While the basic R interface may/may not allow you to resize a window, RStudio's plot windows allow for dynamic resizing with a larger variety of functions. It's also (slightly) less intimidating than the straight command line.  see www.rstudio.org to download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the `plot` function that determines the aspect ratio of the interactive plotting device. Each of the 3 major branches of R has its own default interactive device: Macs has `quartz()`, Windows have (I thought `window()` but checking its help page I am clearly wrong, and checking `?dev.interactive` it is revealed that the correct function is `windows()`), and Linux, `x11()` or `X11()`. If you want to open a device with different dimension than default, you need to issue a command with different height and width values than default (or you can stretch an existing window if your GUI supports that action):

```
  quartz(height = 5, width = 10)
  A <- c(5,4,6,7,3,8,4,2)
  B <- c(2005:2012)
  plot(B, A, type="l")
```

[image]

If you would learn more about the R graphics model you should read: `?Devices`.

After failing to remember the windows interactive device name I see that this might be a cross-platform hack using the fact that the `options` function can provide access to the default device:

```
options()$device(height=5, width=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The distance between the ticks (breaks) on x and y axis are largely defined by your plot and panel dimensions.

**In ggplot2**, you can modify /play around with those by setting fixed coordinate aspect ratios in [`coord_fixed(ratio = x)`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_fixed.html) and/or the panel aspect ratio in [`theme(aspect.ratio = x)`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html), whereby x is a single constant.

Another way to modify the distance between the axis breaks can be by modifying the expansion, e.g. with [`scale_x_continuous(expand = x)`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html) [x being a vector of two numerics] - this squeezes the breaks away from the coordinate limits, thus you can make them get closer.

However, the biggest influencing factor is the device size to which you save the plot, in other words the dimensions of the image that you have in the end. This can be defined in multiple ways and depends on the device you are using for saving. (see IRTFM's answer). `ggsave` is a great way to save your ggplot to a file.